# calling a file jQuery file from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I created some test code that uses Ajax to refresh/update two fields.  It works great
and now, to keep things neat, I have created a file called Ajax.js

In my HTML page where all my fields are, I would like to call this file and make it update
the two variables.

I did the following:

In my HTML page:

```
  <--- included the meta lines needed for the Ajax file ---->
  <--- included: my jQuery includes needed ---------->
  <---- my link to the Ajax.js file -------------->
 <script src="Ajax.js"></script>

 <----- made the call this way, I am not sure is right ------->
 <!----- Ajax Update Fields Function ----->
 <script>
   jQuery('nav').Ajax();
 </script>
```

The call doesn't work, it doesn't update the fields.  Here is the actual Ajax.js code:

```
// JavaScript Document
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 


$(function()
{
  setInterval(function()
   {
$.get("ajax_v00.html",function(data,textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
  var temperature=$(data).filter('#variable1').text()
  var time=$(data).filter('#variable2').text()
  $('#variable1').text(temperature)
  $('#variable2').text(time)
 })
 .fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,errorThrown) //Callback failed
  {
   $('#errors').text("Errors:" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown)
  })
 .done(function() //Callback succeeded
  {
   $('#errors').text('Errors:');
  })
   },1000);
})
```

How can I call this properly?  Hopefully, I explained myself correctly?

Comment: What do you see in the console? What URL are you loading the page through? What is `$(...).Ajax()`?

Comment: If console is my screen's website, I see the first values given, but that is all, it doesn't refresh. I am not sure what you mean with the second question?  $(...).Ajax() is how I imagined that I was suppose to call the function. I really, have no idea on how to call the function, but I would like for it start the second the page is loaded.

Comment: Archer, so if I understand you correctly.  I don't need something that actually calls the function or Ajax.js file, but just including <script src="Ajax.js"></script> it will trigger the function to execute?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the head of your html page...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Ajax.js"></script>
```

Remove the script tags from `Ajax.js`.

Remove `jQuery('nav').Ajax();`  You don't need this.  It's looking for a jQuery function called `Ajax()`, which does not exist.  Your code in `Ajax.js` will already run when the page is loaded as you have wrapped it in the shorthand version of `document.ready`...

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("ajax_v00.html",function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var temperature=$(data).filter('#variable1').text();
            var time=$(data).filter('#variable2').text();
            $('#variable1').text(temperature);
            $('#variable2').text(time);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            $('#errors').text("Errors:" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('#errors').text('Errors:');
        })
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: I tried it, and it seems to get executed once. It actually needs to go there continually to grab the next value, the next, ...etc.  At least it does go in, I can hit F12, place a breakpoint and see that it does go there.  You don't need to invoke it or call it, it runs once.

Comment: I've just tidied the code and added the missing semi-colons, but I can't see any reason why that wouldn't run every second.  Maybe someone will spot something, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Hi Archer, I ran the code (the HTML portion) thru W3 and it found some errors.  I am trying to correct those errors, although I don't think it has anything to do with the Ajax portion.

Comment: I just thought of something, but I don't know how to fix it? variable1 and variable2 are declared in Ajax.js, so even though I use it in .html page, they might only exists inside Ajax.js.  If you feel that, this might be the problem, then how can I make variables 1 & 2 global?

Comment: variable1 and variable2 are not declared in Ajax.js.  They're elements on the page that includes Ajax.js, unless there's more that we haven't seen?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                      jQuery('nav').Ajax();});
  </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did have that originally.... it didn't work so I took out $(document).ready(function() {   });